# mysql get sum of column from subquery while still returning all records

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am trying to return a set of records but also want to include the sum as well.

```
SELECT track_date AS label, track_count AS value
FROM trackers
INNER JOIN (
SELECT tracker_details.track_id, COUNT(track_id) AS track_count, DATE(date_created) AS track_date
    FROM tracker_details
    WHERE (DATE(date_created) >= '2018-01-21' 
    AND DATE(date_created) <= '2018-01-27') 
    AND client_id = 1
    GROUP BY DATE(date_created)) as tracker_details 
ON trackers.track_id = tracker_details.track_id
WHERE trackers.client_id = 1 
ORDER BY DATE(track_date)
```

Currently returns without the sum:

```
label       value
2018-01-21  9
2018-01-22  2
2018-01-26  3
2018-01-27  2
```

By adding the SUM in the select:

```
SELECT track_date AS label, track_count as value, SUM(track_count) as total
```

It is returning:

```
label   value   total
2018-01-22  2   16
```

What I am trying to achieve is:

```
label       value total
2018-01-21  9     16
2018-01-22  2     16
2018-01-26  3     16
2018-01-27  2     16
```

what am i missing?
Any help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT
I was able to resolve this by adding WITH ROLLUP.
'GROUP BY DATE(date_created) WITH ROLLUP'

This created an additional row:

```
label       value
null        21
2018-01-15  2
2018-01-16  5
2018-01-17  1
2018-01-20  4
2018-01-21  9
```

Comment: Trackers doesn't seem to serve any purpose here since the client id appears to be in tracker_details. Can you add sample data as text to your question please.

Comment: Seeing as total is just the sum of value, you could just as easily handle this in your application code, or s bit of JavaScript

Comment: @P.Salmon, in this example, agreed, there are some columns, i will be calling which is only available in trackers table.

Comment: @Strawberry, agree, trying to see if there is a way to do so without building additional loop logic in server side code, but it appears this may not be achievable in some comments below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `SUM()` and other aggregate functions only return one row. You will need to either add the column programmatically after executing the query or add the sum as a sub-query like so:

```
SELECT track_date AS label, track_count AS value,
  (SELECT count(track_id) AS track_sum
   FROM tracker_details
   WHERE (DATE(date_created) >= '2018-01-21' 
          AND DATE(date_created) <= '2018-01-27') 
   AND client_id = 1) as total
FROM trackers
INNER JOIN (
SELECT tracker_details.track_id, COUNT(track_id) AS track_count, DATE(date_created) AS track_date
    FROM tracker_details
    WHERE (DATE(date_created) >= '2018-01-21' 
    AND DATE(date_created) <= '2018-01-27') 
    AND client_id = 1
    GROUP BY DATE(date_created)) as tracker_details 
ON trackers.track_id = tracker_details.track_id
WHERE trackers.client_id = 1 
ORDER BY DATE(track_date)
```

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping to see if there was an easy way to achieve this, but appears that I'll either a) need to add additional sub queries or b) loop and aggregate in the server side .

I did however find that I can use WITH ROLLUP which creates an additional ROW record with NULL identifiers and the last column all summed up.